# Access variable of a class in for loop

Tags: java, class

I'm having trouble accessing a variable of a class I have created within a for loop.

The class I have created is fairly simple and just combines a vector and a double value.

```
public class VectorDistance 
{
    Vector2d v;
    double d;

    public VectorDistance(Vector2d v, double d)
    {
        this.v = v;
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

and within a method in another class which inherits an ArrayList of these vector distances, I'm trying to access the variables of it but it doesn't seem to want to access it. But for whatever reason it won't let me access it. I've tried value.get(0) etc but that does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It is declared as an ArrayList with type VectorDistance throughout the code.

```
public String NewPositionCheck(Vector2d checkPosition, int blockSize, Types.ACTIONS fromPrevious, List<Types.ACTIONS> previousPositions, ArrayList<Observation>[][] grid, int i, ArrayList <VectorDistance> vd)
{
    double closest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (VectorDistance value : vd)
    {

    }
}
```

all i want is to find the smallest value in the ArrayList, by comparing its double value (d) with value "closest" and then store that position as an integer (which i forgot to add)

Comment: Doesn't `value.v` work? If not, your classes would be in different packages. Try providing a `public` getter in that case, and use that.

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't seem to want to access it"? I don't see any attempts to access `value.d` or `value.v` anywhere (which should be fine as long as the classes are in the same package, otherwise make the fields `public` or add getters); what was your previous attempt and what issues were you running in to?

Comment: Basically you want to read a good tutorial on the basics of Java; for example on the visibility of member fields in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare them public, to access them outside of its class

```
public Vector2d v;
public double d;
```

Or much better solution is to create getters/setters (just google it)

Also - modern IDE like netbeans, eclipse etc. even have option to create getters/setters for you)

Comment: yes, silly me, forgot to make them public. literally been pulling my hair out for an hour. thanks :)

Comment: I wouldnt automatically say that getters/setters are "better" than accessing elements. In its core nature, some objects are DTOs (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object ). As Robert Martin says: "Beans have private variables manipulated by getters and setters. The quasi-encapsulation of beans seems to make some OO purists feel better but usually provides no other benefit."

Comment: @Jägermeister - you never know, when you need slight change in get/set the variable, the damage caused by not having getters and setters in that scenario can be huge. But having getters/setters cause "no other benefit" at its worst.

Comment: @libik Lets put it that way: I think that the "ideal" solution would be that you **only** have attributes, but with (optional) "hidden" getter/setter methods behind it (called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle by Bertrand Meyer many years ago). So, the next best thing might be real getters/setters. But I have seen far too many beans that were simply DTO objects; and that stayed like that for their whole lifetime; just with a lot of useless boilerplate clutter code ... Point is: code is read many many many times, too. So, dont waste the readers attention for no reason.

Comment: @Jägermeister - you cant have "hidden" getter/setter in Java, if you need/want them, you have to use for example c#. As you dont have them in Java, you have to use getter/setter for uniform access. For simple objects, the getters/setters do not lower the readability, cause they are simple :). In complex class, getters/setters is must. btw : you are "identifying" problem, but you do not have solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify access modifier as public as below:

```
    public class VectorDistance 
    {
        public Vector2d v;
        public double d;

        public VectorDistance(Vector2d v, double d)
        {
            this.v = v;
            this.d = d;
        }
    }
```

More professional way would be declaring access methods, with the name getSomething() or setSomething(ValueType val)

Comment: yes, silly me, forgot to make them public. literally been pulling my hair out for an hour. thanks :)